# Socket help in java

Tags: java, sockets

I have looked a lots of examples and have asked a few people but no one seems to be able to tell me what I am doing wrong on my listen sockets. Please help.

I am making a program that reads from 3 files and then sends data in sockets in threads.
here is every thing I have done

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    //making all threads for A,B and C
    Thread T_A = new Thread(new threads ("A"));
    Thread T_B = new Thread(new threads ("B"));
    Thread T_C = new Thread(new threads ("C"));
    //starting the threads for A,B and C
    T_A.start();
    T_B.start();
    T_C.start();
    }
}
```

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class threads implements Runnable {
        //making temps
        String name;
        int listen;
        int send;
        String line;
        BufferedReader reader;
        BufferedReader input;
        boolean Listening=false;
        boolean Sending=false;
        PrintWriter output;
        ServerSocket node_listen=null;
        Socket node_send=null;
        Socket node_rev=null;

        public threads(String x){
            //name of thead A,B or C
            name=x;                
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){
        try{
            //openinng the conf file for thread
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("conf" + name + ".txt"));
            //this is for node A because it only sends info does not get info
            if(name.equals("A")==true){
                //making a socket to send on
                System.out.println("Node " + name + " is starting");
                send = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
                for(int temp=0;temp!=5;temp++)
                {
                    temp=Checker(temp);
                }
            }
            //this is for node B becuase it sends and gets info
            else if(name.equals("B")==true){
                //getting ports for send and listen
                listen = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
                send = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
                System.out.println("Node " + name + " is starting");
                Listening=setUpListen();                
                for(int temp=0;temp!=5;temp++)
                {
                    temp=Checker(temp);
                }
            }       
            //node C only gets info
            else if(name.equals("C")==true){
                //geting listen port
                listen = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
                System.out.println("Node " + name + " is starting");
                Listening=setUpListen();
            }
            //sends and gets data until it has no more to send or get
            while(Listening==true || Sending== true)
            {
                //while it needs to get data and was a node that gets data
                if(Listening==true)
                {
                    Listen();
                }
                //Has not sent terminate yet and is a sending node
                if(Sending==true)
                {
                    Send();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException | NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }   
        catch (InterruptedException ex)
        { 
                Logger.getLogger(threads.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("Node " + name + " has ended");
    }

    public boolean setUpConnection(){
        try {
            //making a socket for sending
            System.out.println("Node " + name + " is setting up connection");
            node_send = new Socket("hostname", send);
            output = new PrintWriter(node_send.getOutputStream(),true);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("Error setting up socket connection: " + name + " :" + send);
            return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error setting up socket connection: " + name + " " + e);
            return false;
            }
        //telling the thread it is a sending thread
        Sending=true;
        System.out.println("Node " + name + " is ready for sending");
        return true;
    }

    public boolean setUpListen(){
    try{
        //making socket for Listening
        System.out.println("Node " + name + " is setting up listen");
        nodeListen = new ServerSocket(listen);
        System.out.println("Node " + name + " is trying to listen");
        node_rev = node_listen.accept();
        System.out.println("Node " + name + " NEVER GETS HERE");
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(node_rev.getInputStream()));
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                System.out.println("Error setting up socket connection: " + name + " :" + listen);
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error setting up socket connection: " + name + " " + e);
                return false;
        }
        //telling the thread it is a Listening thread
        System.out.println("Node " + name + " is ready for listening");
        return true;
    }

    public void Listen(){
        try{
            line = input.readLine();
            //As long as something was sent and it was not terminate prints data
            if(line.equals("terminate")==false&&line.equals("null")==false)
            {
                System.out.println("Node " + name + " received:" + line);
            }
            //When terminate was sent it no longer looks for data 
            if(line.equals("terminate"))
            {
                Listening=false;
                node_listen.close();
                node_rev.close();
                input.close();
                System.out.println("Node " + name + " done listening");
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error Listening on connection: " + name + " " + e);
        }
    }

    public void Send(){
        try{
        //reads in the data and sends it to node
        line=reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        output.println(line);
        //if the data sent was terminate then exit sending mode
        if(line.equals("terminate")==true)
            {
                Sending=false;
                node_send.close();
                output.close();
                System.out.println("Node " + name + " done sending");
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error Sending on connection: " + name + " " + e);
        }
    }

    public int Checker(int temp) throws InterruptedException{
        boolean connected=setUpConnection();
            if(connected==true)
            {
                    //connected
                    temp=5;
            }
            return temp;
        }
}
```

each conf file is setup like this

confA.txt

```txt
5002
This is a sample line of text for node A.
This is another sample line of text for node A.
Node B will be printing out these three lines for node A.
terminate
```

confB.txt

```txt
5002
5005
This is a sample line of text.
This is another sample line of text.
Node C will be printing out these three lines.
terminate
```

confC.txt

```txt
5005
```

That is the out put I get

```txt
run:
Node A is starting
Node A is setting up connection
Node B is starting
Node B is setting up listen
Node C is starting
Node C is setting up listen
Node B is trying to listen
Node C is trying to listen
Error setting up socket connection: A java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
Node A is setting up connection
Error setting up socket connection: A java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
Node A is setting up connection
Error setting up socket connection: A java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
Node A is setting up connection
Error setting up socket connection: A java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
Node A is setting up connection
Error setting up socket connection: A java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
Node A has ended
```

The code never seems to get to the line System.out.println("Node " + name + " NEVER GETS HERE"); in the setUpListen();

Thanks

Comment: Just a heads up, you can do `if(<boolean>)` instead of `if(<boolean> == true)`.

Comment: Cool I learned something new. Thanks. 

Wow I had a lot of them. lol

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a Server Side or Client Side? Because these are two different connections.

Comment: I am trying setup a Server to listen.
Then setup a Client to send.
My Server is just hanging on node_rev = node_listen.accept(); so the Client never can send and closes after 5 trys.

Comment: Never mind the server, what about the five connect timeout exceptions?

Comment: What exactly is what you want to achieve? Do you want to read a file and send the bytes to a connected client using a `Socket`?

Answer (score 2):

That is because `ServerSocket.accept()` blocks until an incoming connection is reported. The method returns the `Socket`.

So the next line (`System.out.println("Node " + name + " NEVER GETS HERE")`) is never executed until you get another network interface to connect to your listening `ServerSocket`.

I don't know exactly what it is you're trying to achieve, but you need to listen for incoming connections in an apart thread:

```java
final ServerSocket serverSocket = createServerSocket();
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Incoming connection from " + socket.getInetAddress());
        doSomethingWithSocket(socket);
    }
}).start();
```

---

*PS: Please persist with the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf):*

- *Classes should always start with an Uppercase letter;*
- *Field names (or class attributes) should always start with a lowercase letter;*
- *Method names should always start with a lowercase letter.*

Comment: I will work on the Naming Convention. I did not know Java had them this is my first java project. Thanks

Comment: Then you've just started with not the easiest part, I think.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my problem was node_send = new Socket("hostname", send); should have been node_send = new Socket("localhost", send);

I am dumb.

However I want to thank everyone for there help and pointers.

Answer (score -1):

public class threads ?? Conventions please.

O.t:

```
Error setting up socket connection: C java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

The port that setted up each listener on, is the same. (i.e Address already in use.)

Comment: ops that was an old output. That was me testing just putting in the port. My code no longer does that part. I edited it with the new output